# Intellij 2020.3.2 only starts once / never able to start again after closing

Tags: intellij-idea, installation, startup

im really lost here, re-installed multiple times and every time i open intellij for the first time it works but after that it just doesnt do anything..

tried suggestions i found on the internet like editing the idea.exe.vmoptions file but to no result. Most suggesstions says that you have to increase xms and xmx but that did nothing for me.

this is the original idea.exe.vmoptions:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=384m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
```

edit: running the idea.bat from command line DOES start intelliJ gives this warning:

```
 C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 
 2020.3.2\bin>.\idea.bat
 OpenJDK Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in 
 version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please try running from the command line using idea.bat file, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line. What errors do you see? If it hangs on start, please provide the thread dumps per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899. See if the steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559 help.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i just updated my post. it does start intellij when running from calling the idea.bat file.. you have any idea why?

Comment: If you don't see any new messages when running via .bat file and no UI is shown, it's likely that the IDE is frozen. Use Ctrl+Break to get the thread dump as described at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899.

Comment: took a bit bit i got it! any idea how i can get the dump to you? it was to large for stackoverflow and it wont allow me posting a wetransfer link..

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new and attach the logs/dumps to the support ticket.

Comment: alright will do that!               thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the corrupted or incomplete OS installation / system libraries missing.

Logs contained the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\jbr\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

The issue was fixed by reinstalling https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe.